# Typescript: Navigator merging with lib.d.ts

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'm confused about merging with lib.d.ts. I am trying to add a property to Navigator. I think I need to merge with Navigator interface that is declared in lib.d.ts. I am using TS 2.0.6.

Here is my code:

```
let lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
```

Which produces this error:

> Property 'userLanguage' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

I've tried making a merge happen this way:

```
interface Navigator {
    userLanguage: string;
}
```

But, still cannot find the userLanguage property...

Can someone help me understand where and how I can merge with lib.d.ts declarations?

Thank-you

Comment: Have you really loaded file containing `interface Navigator` by compilator/IDE? Try to add link pointing to file containing `Interface Navigator` in header of file where extended object is used by comment like `/// <reference path="Navigator.ts" />`. Playground don't highlight error too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out I did not realize that I had to create a navigator.d.ts file with the interface in it. Once that file was created in my project, errors went away.

I did not need to use the  ///< reference ...

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to creating a type definition file, as in the accepted answer, is to access the "userLanguage" property using a string literal, like so:

```
navigator['userLanguage'] //=> OK

navigator.userLanguage //=> TS2339: Property ‘userLanguage’ does not exist on type ‘Navigator’
```